# Apply multiple classes doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

Basicly i have a div, and want to do a exercise where i apply 3 diferent classes using vue.js, to do that i try to use v-bind:class, more precise :class, can i bind a class directly from css?

I did something like that

**html**

```
<div :style="[myClass1,myClass2,myClass3]">I got no class :(</div>
```

**css**

```
.myClass1 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 200px !important;
  height: 200px !important;
}

.myClass2 {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.myClass3 {
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#exercise',
  data: {
    effect: true,
  },
  methods: {
    startEffect: function() {
      var vm = this;
      setInterval(function(){
        vm.effect = !vm.effect;
        console.log(this.effect);
      },1000);
    }
  }
});
```

so if i can't bind the classes directly how can i do that with vue.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind styles to `style` and classes to `class`. In the html example, you are trying to bind classes to `style`

Also, the way you are listing the classes, they are pointing to values that are not present in the js example. You should either add them in `data` or wrap them with quotes: `<div :class="['myClass1','myClass2','myClass3']">Yay, classes!</div>`

Read more in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax).

Answer (score 2):

Check the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax) for array syntax of dynamic classes, you have to use `v-bind:class` in the code.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#exercise',
  data: {
    effect: true
  },
  methods: {
    startEffect: function() {
      var vm = this;
      setInterval(function(){
        vm.effect = !vm.effect;
        console.log(this.effect);
      },1000);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.myClass1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px !important;
  height: 200px !important;
}

.myClass2 {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.myClass3 {
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="exercise">
<div v-bind:class="['myClass1','myClass2','myClass3']">I got no class :(</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div v-bind:class="[myClass1,myClass2,myClass3]">I have your classes</div>
```

[Please see documentation for details](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)